# Postfix calc only works with proper spacing(i.e. 3 14 2*7/ throws an exception)

Tags: java, stringtokenizer, rpn, postfix-notation

The code posted works for operations but wont work if there isnt spacing between the operators and operands.

I was given 4 expressions to compute

1. 10 2 8 * + 3 -
2. 3 14+2*7/
3. 4 2 + 3 15 1 - * +
4. 1 2 + 3 % 6 - 2 3 + /

(spacing is important)

Expression two is the one that will not compute using my current calculator

Here is my code

```
  import java.util.*;
  public class PostFix {

   public static void main(String []args){

    Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<Integer>();
    System.out.println("Input your expression using postfix notation");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String expr = input.nextLine();
        StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(expr);

    while(tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()){
        String c = tokenizer.nextToken();
        if(c.startsWith("0")|| c.startsWith("1")||c.startsWith("2")||c.startsWith("3")||c.startsWith("4")||
            c.startsWith("5")||c.startsWith("6")||c.startsWith("7")||c.startsWith("8")||c.startsWith("9"))
            stack.push(Integer.parseInt(c));
        else if(c.equals("+")){
            int op1 = stack.pop();
            int op2= stack.pop();
            stack.push(op2+op1);
        }
        else if(c.equals("-")){
            int op1 = stack.pop();
            int op2= stack.pop();
            stack.push(op2-op1);
        }
        else if(c.equals("*")){
            int op1 = stack.pop();
            int op2= stack.pop();
            stack.push(op2*op1);
        }
        else if(c.equals("/")){
            int op1 = stack.pop();
            int op2= stack.pop();
            stack.push(op2/op1);
        }
        else if(c.equals("%")){
            int op1 = stack.pop();
            int op2= stack.pop();
            stack.push(op1%op2);
        }



    }
System.out.println(stack.pop());

}
   }
```

Here is the StackTrace

```
 Input your expression using postfix notation
 3 14+2*7/
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string:  "14+2*7/"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
at PostFix.main(PostFix.java:18)
```

Comment: The exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException

Comment: `StringTokenizer` is not good enough because it basically just looks for whitespace and returns the stuff in between, so it will return `"14+2*7/"` as a token.  `StreamTokenizer` is more sophisticated.  Another solution would be to create a regular expression and set up a `Matcher` that can find whatever you define to be a token; see this [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/).

Comment: Can you post your full StackTrace?

Comment: @hichris123 of the exception that was thrown?

Comment: Yes, of that exception.

Comment: Also after reading the api for StringTokenizer there is a constructor that takes three parameters String str  String delim, boolean returnDelims. Im assuming i could use that to help solve this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really have to use `StringTokenizer`, construct it like this:

```
StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(expr, " +-*/%", true);
```

The second parameter says that spaces and all the operators are considered delimiters, in addition to spaces.  The third parameter says that the delimiters are treated as tokens, so when it sees `"+"`, `"-"`, etc., it will return that as a string.  It will also return spaces, so you have to make sure that when `nextToken` returns `" "`, you ignore it and don't treat it as an error.

Answer (score 0):

Use a StreamTokenizer for parsing, see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/StreamTokenizer.html

```
StreamTokenizer tokenizer = new StreamTokenizer(new StringReader(expr));
tokenizer.ordinaryChar('/');  // see comments

while(tokenizer.nextToken() != StreamTokenizer.TT_EOF){
  if (tonenizer.ttype == StreamTokenizer.TT_NUMBER) {
    stack.push(Integer.parseInt(tokenizer.sval));
  } else {
    int op1 = stack.pop();
    int op2 = stack.pop();
    switch (ttype) {
      case '+': op2 += op1; break;
      case '-': op2 -= op1; break;
      case '*': op2 *= op1; break;
      case '/': op2 /= op1; break;
    }
    stack.push(op2);
  }
}
```

Comment: I am kind of new to java, what exactly is a StreamTokenizer?

Comment: It's a tokenizer for c-like languages, including the corresponding expressions.

Comment: after reading my assignment sheet again i am actually supposed to use the StringTokenizer object to split up the String

Comment: @StefanHaustein FYI: I couldn't get your code to work right except by adding `tokenizer.ordinaryChar('/');`.  Otherwise it seemed to want to do something special with the slash character (probably because it also recognizes C and C++ comments).

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, if you can't use StreamTokenizer, use the 3-argument version of the StringTokenizer constructor:

```
StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(expr, " +*-/", true);
```

This will make ' ', '+', '*', '-' and '/' delimiters and also report them as tokens.